# create an ID column with randomly generated values in R

Tags: r, function

I am using the package called `mtcars` and I want to get a randomly generated number for every observations. I have written a function:

```
mtcars$ID <- NULL
for (i in mtcars){
  mtcars$ID <- runif(1, min=0, max=100)
}
```

However, this assigns the same number to all cars.

I tried:

```
mtcars$ID <- NULL
for (i in mtcars){
  mtcars$ID[i] <- runif(1, min=0, max=100)
}
```

which results in an error. I would like to get two type of results (two functions):

1. to assign a random number to each observation
2. to assign a unique random number to each observation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are of course a plenty of easier ways to assign random values to `ID` column.

Seems OP is only interested in the solutions with `for` loop, then here are some examples to make it

1. to assign a random number to each observation:

```
for (i in seq(nrow(mtcars))){
  mtcars$ID[i] <- runif(1, min=0, max=100) # assign random value which might be duplicated (but with low probability if you don't have super many rows) 
}
```

2. to assign a ***unique*** random number to each observation

```
for (i in seq(nrow(mtcars))){
  repeat {
    r <- runif(1, min=0, max=100)
    if (!r %in% mtcars$ID) break # if generated random number is not in the existing values, then terminate the loop and go to value assignment in the next step
  }
  mtcars$ID[i] <- r
}
```

Comment: thanks @ThomasIsCoding. Why do i need to use seq(nrow(mtcars)) instead mtcars directly?

Comment: @Danka if you use `for (i in mtcars) ...`, `i` refers to the elements in `mtcars`, i.e., columns of `mtcars`, which are lists, rather than row numbers.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `sample` on the number of rows in the dataset.

```
mtcars$ID <- sample(nrow(mtcars))
```

The range for this would be from 1 to number of rows in data and it would be randomly assigned to every row.

It can also be wrapped in a function if needed :

```
get_a_unique_id <- function(data) sample(nrow(data))

mtcars$ID <- get_a_unique_id(mtcars)
iris$ID <- get_a_unique_id(iris)
```

---

Regarding OP's attempt on `for` loop. `NULL` deletes the column whereas `NA` initializes it with `NA`.Since there is no column present in `mtcars`, it results in an error. Also the loop `for (i in mtcars){` loops over the column values and not rows. Try

```
 for (i in mtcars){
    print(i)
 }
```

Hence, it should be

```
mtcars$ID <- NA 
for (i in seq_len(nrow(mtcars))){
   mtcars$ID[i] <- runif(1, min=0, max=100)
}
```

However, even this does not guarantee 100% on having a unique value for each row since with `runif` we can have same numbers.

Comment: yes, thanks. but i still would like to find ouut how to write the function in a way that eveery row has a different number?

Comment: @Danka If you try the above method, every row would have a different number.

Comment: yes, the result is thee same (and the way you get to it is better) but i want to learn how to write the function

Comment: I am not clear about what you are looking for but you can wrap the same thing into a function and use it for different datasets. I have updated the answer.

Comment: i want to know why by using mtcars$ID[i] i get an error and how to change my function so i get a different number for eevery row

Comment: @Danka I have updated the answer with some explanation.